# My javascript function gets stuck in a loop...

Tags: javascript, function, loops, logic

i'm having trouble understanding where my logic fails! When I try to impose a word.length condition on pushing the word i've got from a paragraph in an array, i get stuck in an infinite loop. Please let me know your thoughts, thanks to all!

```
var str = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML;
console.log(str);



function wordIndexes(str) {
    var result = [];
    var len = str.length;
    var i = 0, j, word;

    while (i < len) {
        if (str[i] === ' ') {
            ++i;
        }
        else {
            word = "";
            for (j = i; j < len && str[j] !== ' '; ++j) {
                word += str[j];
            }

              console.log(word.length);

            //imposing length conditions
              if (word.length < 4)
               {console.log('too short')}

              else {    
              result.push([i, word]);
              i = j;
              };


        }
    }
    return result;  
}
```

Comment: it should be i++ not ++i i think

Comment: Could you explain in words what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: and add some HTML code.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle for this and post the link.... include data so people can play with it.  http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: What str are you passing in? Everything helps.

Comment: @GintasK in this code `i` is not part of an expression, so pre-incrementing it or post-incrementing it doesn't matter.

Comment: Missing a ";" at the end of the line "console.log('too short')". But it's not the reason for an infinite loop :)

Comment: @Ricola3D `;` in javascript are optional if its only one instruction in line

Answer (score 3):

If the word length is less than 4 your code logs a message, but doesn't update `i`, so the next iteration starts at the same point, and fails at the same point.

I'd suggest an alternative but it's not clear how you intend to handle this condition.

Comment: Hello mike many thanks for your answer, it was indeed the problem, and it now works

Answer (score 0):

```
if (word.length < 4)
{
  console.log('too short')
}
else
{
  ...
```

If you go in this condition, the i counter doesn't change. Check you don't go in this condition everytime

Comment: Thank you Ric you were right also, i forgot to update to i counter. Its all fixed now!

Answer (score 0):

You missed i =j  in  your if statement

```
if (word.length < 4)
{
  console.log('too short')

i = j  // You missed this

}
```